# Selenium+Java - Unable to find WebElements in page

Tags: java, selenium, paypal

I'm doing some automation bits for work and right now I'm trying to automate a purchase through our storefront that should go to the paypal sandbox and complete the purchase. Everything looks good and I know the general flow works but I'm having trouble finding the webElements when I get to the first PayPal page.

The PayPal side of the flow consists of 2 pages. One to input the login information and another one to confirm the purchase. The second page works perfectly but the first one always gives me "Unable to find element" when I tell it to look for the email/password field and the login button. If make the driver print out the current URL for debugging purposes it correctly prints the payPal URL so it is looking at the right site. I also tried putting a 30 seconds delay to make sure it wasn't a timing issue and I get the same problem.

Here's the class file in question:

```
public class PayPalLoginPage extends AbstractPaymentPage {
    //AbstractPaymentPage extends from AbrstractPageObject

      private WebElement email; //Element ID is email
      private WebElement password; //Element ID is password
      @FindBy(id = "btnLogin")
      private WebElement loginButton;

      public PayPalLoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }


      public PayPalPurchaseConfirmationPage login (PayPalInfo payPalInfo) {
        email.sendKeys(payPalInfo.getEmail());
        password.sendKeys(payPalInfo.getPassword());
        loginButton.click();
        this.waitForPayPalLoadingCurtainToDisappear();
        return new PayPalPurchaseConfirmationPage(this.getDriver());
      }
```

The way I'm calling this class is like this:

```
case PAYPAL_PURCHASE:
  setDriver(new PayPalLoginPage(getDriver()).login(getPaymentMethod()).confirmPayPalPurchase());
  break;
```

So, the flow works perfectly up until it gets to the first payPal page and it just stops saying it can't find any of those 3 elements. If I set it to just wait there and manually fill up the information then it picks right up on the next page and works from them on (finding all the elements on the 2nd payPal page and acting on them).

I get the same behavior if I put the findElement.By line inside the login method and also the same result regardless of whether I'm trying to find them using id, name, xpath or css.

Any idea on what I could be missing?.

Answer (score 0):

You are just defining the email and followings as WebElement but not assigning them to any webelement. See the following:

```
private WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email_text_box_id"));
private WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password_text_box_id"));
private WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("login_button_id"));
```

if you want `PageObject` to assign WebElements then you need to call the `initElement` inside of a case:

```
public class PayPalLoginPage extends AbstractPaymentPage {
//AbstractPaymentPage extends from AbrstractPageObject

  private WebElement email; //Element ID is email
  private WebElement password; //Element ID is password
  @FindBy(id = "btnLogin")
  private WebElement loginButton;

  public PayPalPurchaseConfirmationPage login (PayPalInfo payPalInfo) {
    email.sendKeys(payPalInfo.getEmail());
    password.sendKeys(payPalInfo.getPassword());
    loginButton.click();
    this.waitForPayPalLoadingCurtainToDisappear();
    return new PayPalPurchaseConfirmationPage(this.getDriver());
  }
}
```

Call  the PayPal login function:

```
public class UsingPayPalLoginPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Create a new instance of a driver
      WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

      // Create a new instance of the PayPall page
      // and initialise any WebElement fields in it.
      PayPalLoginPage page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, PayPalLoginPage.class);

      // call login of paypal.
      page.login(payPalInfo);
  }
}
```

Comment: As long as the variable has the same name as the element's ID or Name the "PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);" line should do that assignment by default. I'm using it that same way in all the other pageObject classes and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the update but I'm getting the same error. 

`case PAYPAL_PURCHASE:
          PayPalLoginPage payPalLoginPage = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), PayPalLoginPage.class);
          setDriver(payPalLoginPage.login((PayPalInfo) customerInfo.getPaymentMethod()).confirmPayPalPurchase());
          break;`
Still returns the 'unable to find element' message.

Comment: with `setDriver(new PayPalLoginPage(getDriver()).login(getPaymentMethod()).confirmPayPalPurchase());` you are calling page class you need to call `UsingPayPalLoginPage`

Comment: Thanks but I added that new class and I'm still having the same problem. 
I also tried to remove all the pageFactory stuff and simply do this at the start of the login method: 
`email = webDriver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    email.sendKeys(payPalInfo.getEmail());`
And I still get the element not found exception... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong >.<.